# Why does \uchyph=0 not work for me?

Tags: xetex, hyphenation, capitalization

Why does `\uchyph=0` not work for me?
It is in my preamble, but Istill get names of people hyphenated.

Is it a font issue?

I typeset with XeLaTeX.

---

Minimal example: try with XeLaTeX with and without `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some Textual Material.
Some Textual Material.
Some Textual Material.
Some Textual Material.
Some Textual Material.
Some Textual Material.
Some Textual Material.

\uchyph=0 %
\noindent
Some Textual Material.
Some Textual Material.
Some Textual Material.
Some Textual Material.
Some Textual Material.
Some Textual Material.
Some Textual Material.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have a feeling this is to do with loading fonts using the 'extended' (system font) interface. I put together a MWE, and it works 'correctly' (`\uchyph` has an effect) if I do not load `fontpsec`, but fails if I do. The `fontspec` package automatically loads the Latin Modern OTF font, and I have a feeling this is where the trouble starts: using XeTeX and the 'traditional' `lmodern` package does not cause a problem.

Comment: @tohecz I've edited in my MWE, as the issue does not seem to be related to a specific font.

Comment: I suspect this is a XeTeX bug: see http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2007-June/006601.html (from 2007!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I use several documents as input to my article. It seems I need to include `\uchyph=0` in each of these separate documents. I always assumed that having `uchyph` in the preamble would make it effective globally.